# ESP8266 Wifi-Sniffer doesn't collect SSIDs (Probe Request / Probe Frame)

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to get the following project running:
https://github.com/kalanda/esp8266-sniffer

The project is about Probe Frame / Probe Request. It let's a simple ESP8266 act like a WLAN Router, and collect all incoming Probe Frames. Every Probe Frame should include the MAC address of the device, and one SSID of it's saved networks. That's it.

I have copied the code of the project on my ESP8266.
I have 3 different smartphones laying around.
So now, when I look in the Serial Monitor, I should see all the packages from my 3 smartphones, every package should include the MAC address of the smartphone, and also one of the saved SSID's, which it was connected to in the past.

I see everything, except for the SSID's.
I can see the Probe Frames, coming from my different smartphones, but the SSID's are just blank.

Anyone has a idea?

Here is the complete code of the project.
Also, I have attached a screenshot of my Serial Monitor output. I have just painted the MAC addresses of my smartphones green. So as you can see, no SSIDs.

I'm very thankful for EVERY help or idea!

Thanks in advance,

EMHA.

[SCREENSHOT OF SERIAL MONITOR OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qSxf.jpg)

```
#include <Arduino.h>

extern "C" {
  #include <user_interface.h>
}

#define DATA_LENGTH           112

#define TYPE_MANAGEMENT       0x00
#define TYPE_CONTROL          0x01
#define TYPE_DATA             0x02
#define SUBTYPE_PROBE_REQUEST 0x04

struct RxControl {
 signed rssi:8; // signal intensity of packet
 unsigned rate:4;
 unsigned is_group:1;
 unsigned:1;
 unsigned sig_mode:2; // 0:is 11n packet; 1:is not 11n packet;
 unsigned legacy_length:12; // if not 11n packet, shows length of packet.
 unsigned damatch0:1;
 unsigned damatch1:1;
 unsigned bssidmatch0:1;
 unsigned bssidmatch1:1;
 unsigned MCS:7; // if is 11n packet, shows the modulation and code used (range from 0 to 76)
 unsigned CWB:1; // if is 11n packet, shows if is HT40 packet or not
 unsigned HT_length:16;// if is 11n packet, shows length of packet.
 unsigned Smoothing:1;
 unsigned Not_Sounding:1;
 unsigned:1;
 unsigned Aggregation:1;
 unsigned STBC:2;
 unsigned FEC_CODING:1; // if is 11n packet, shows if is LDPC packet or not.
 unsigned SGI:1;
 unsigned rxend_state:8;
 unsigned ampdu_cnt:8;
 unsigned channel:4; //which channel this packet in.
 unsigned:12;
};

struct SnifferPacket{
    struct RxControl rx_ctrl;
    uint8_t data[DATA_LENGTH];
    uint16_t cnt;
    uint16_t len;
};

// Declare each custom function (excluding built-in, such as setup and loop) before it will be called.
// https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/faq.html#convert-arduino-file-to-c-manually
static void showMetadata(SnifferPacket *snifferPacket);
static void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR sniffer_callback(uint8_t *buffer, uint16_t length);
static void printDataSpan(uint16_t start, uint16_t size, uint8_t* data);
static void getMAC(char *addr, uint8_t* data, uint16_t offset);
void channelHop();

static void showMetadata(SnifferPacket *snifferPacket) {

  unsigned int frameControl = ((unsigned int)snifferPacket->data[1] << 8) + snifferPacket->data[0];

  uint8_t version      = (frameControl & 0b0000000000000011) >> 0;
  uint8_t frameType    = (frameControl & 0b0000000000001100) >> 2;
  uint8_t frameSubType = (frameControl & 0b0000000011110000) >> 4;
  uint8_t toDS         = (frameControl & 0b0000000100000000) >> 8;
  uint8_t fromDS       = (frameControl & 0b0000001000000000) >> 9;

  // Only look for probe request packets
  if (frameType != TYPE_MANAGEMENT ||
      frameSubType != SUBTYPE_PROBE_REQUEST)
        return;

  Serial.print("RSSI: ");
  Serial.print(snifferPacket->rx_ctrl.rssi, DEC);

  Serial.print(" Ch: ");
  Serial.print(wifi_get_channel());

  char addr[] = "00:00:00:00:00:00";
  getMAC(addr, snifferPacket->data, 10);
  Serial.print(" Peer MAC: ");
  Serial.print(addr);

  uint8_t SSID_length = snifferPacket->data[25];
  Serial.print(" SSID: ");
  printDataSpan(26, SSID_length, snifferPacket->data);

  Serial.println();
}

/**
 * Callback for promiscuous mode
 */
static void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR sniffer_callback(uint8_t *buffer, uint16_t length) {
  struct SnifferPacket *snifferPacket = (struct SnifferPacket*) buffer;
  showMetadata(snifferPacket);
}

static void printDataSpan(uint16_t start, uint16_t size, uint8_t* data) {
  for(uint16_t i = start; i < DATA_LENGTH && i < start+size; i++) {
    Serial.write(data[i]);
  }
}

static void getMAC(char *addr, uint8_t* data, uint16_t offset) {
  sprintf(addr, "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", data[offset+0], data[offset+1], data[offset+2], data[offset+3], data[offset+4], data[offset+5]);
}

#define CHANNEL_HOP_INTERVAL_MS   1000
static os_timer_t channelHop_timer;

/**
 * Callback for channel hoping
 */
void channelHop()
{
  // hoping channels 1-13
  uint8 new_channel = wifi_get_channel() + 1;
  if (new_channel > 13) {
    new_channel = 1;
  }
  wifi_set_channel(new_channel);
}

#define DISABLE 0
#define ENABLE  1

void setup() {
  // set the WiFi chip to "promiscuous" mode aka monitor mode
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  wifi_set_opmode(STATION_MODE);
  wifi_set_channel(1);
  wifi_promiscuous_enable(DISABLE);
  delay(10);
  wifi_set_promiscuous_rx_cb(sniffer_callback);
  delay(10);
  wifi_promiscuous_enable(ENABLE);

  // setup the channel hoping callback timer
  os_timer_disarm(&channelHop_timer);
  os_timer_setfn(&channelHop_timer, (os_timer_func_t *) channelHop, NULL);
  os_timer_arm(&channelHop_timer, CHANNEL_HOP_INTERVAL_MS, 1);
}

void loop() {
  delay(10);
}
```

Comment: Try to change the `Serial.write()` within the `printDataSpan()` function to `Serial.print()`, or alternatively add one extra line of `Serial.print()` to print the same data to Serial Monitor. If you want to learn from someone's example code, don't just be a 'copy-and-paste' programmer, read the document of [Serial.write()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/write/) and [Serial.print()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print/) to understand the differences.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried it. Same result. But good to see that the same thing came to your mind. :-)
Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

The probe requests that you are recording most probably do not even contain an SSID.

Directed probes (targetting a specific SSID) came somewhat out of fashion, mainly for privacy reasons (clients are revealing the SSID they are looking for). What you are seeing are broadcast probe requests. Basically the same thing, but difference is that they do contain an SSID. All access points that receive such probe request frames reply with a probe response, this way allowing the client to aggregate a list of networks in range.

Directed probe requests nowadays are only sent just right before a (re-) connection is established. So maybe it helps if you disconnect/reconnect some clients from the Wi-Fi network to test your code?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! As my englisch is not perfect, I‘m not 100% sure if I get what you mean. So do you mean I would need to connect to the smartphone, to get the SSIDs of it? Is there any way to get s list of all the favorite saved SSIDs of this smartphone, without connecting to it? Means, I would like to just listen. I don‘t want to connect to the smartphone(s). Is it possible? Or would I need to connect to it?